# callback not executing after Jquery serializing and $post

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I was wondering whether anyone can let me now whats wrong with my code when posting data to a php script.

```
$('#subscribe-form').submit(function(){

            $.post('php/insert.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            alert(data);

            })
})
```

For some reason the callback is not being executed even though the data is being sent. I know this cos it inserts into the database.  Can anyone tell me where im going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you outputting in your response from insert.php?

Comment: Im echoing out the values sent from the form. Im not even able to execute an alert("String") in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible help I see in the [jQuery.post() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is this:

Additional Notes:

- Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
- If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method or. As of jQuery 1.5, the .error()method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.post() is also available for error handling.

So, maybe you need to hook the various error returns and see if it's returning any sort of error.

Comment: okay thanks alot @jfriend00. I will give that a shot and let you know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the javascript log? its called Javascript console in chrome but i know firefox has something similar.

Comment: yeah the log only shows that the form data is being posted. not returned.